# Is it possible to setRotation in ol.View with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-3

I am using the [setRotation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#setRotation) method for an `ol.View` similar to the examples available at the [openlayers examples](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/examples/) page. I have an encoded polyline that is drawn on the map and then we fit to the extent of that layer and if necessary rotate the map.

This all works great with [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) and even a custom imagery service. This will not work with any of the Google tile services though. Is there any support for rotation of the `ol.View` with Google map services, if so, any examples? I didn't see any comments in the [API documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.View.html) for `ol.View` and Google map services.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotate control only for 45° imagery see code like this:

```
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.518970, -122.672899),
      zoom: 18,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      heading: 90,
      tilt: 45
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }

  function rotate90() {
    var heading = map.getHeading() || 0;
    map.setHeading(heading + 90);
  }

  function autoRotate() {
    // Determine if we're showing aerial imagery
    if (map.getTilt() != 0) {
      window.setInterval(rotate90, 3000);
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

You can see an example [google45°](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#45DegreeImagery)

But for normal google maps the rotation is not avaliable.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenLayers.